# Remove an Application in Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-management

I've created several Apps in Azure Active Directory and some of them I don't need anymore. I want to remove them but the remove icon at the bottom is greyed out.
Does anyone know what the reason for this could be or if there is another way to remove the Apps I don't need?

Comment: Could you provide the error interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the applications are multi tenant, first thing you would need to do is to change that so that they are not multi tenant. Then you should be able to remove the applications from your Azure AD.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me when I had similar problems, check it out:
https://samlman.wordpress.com/2015/02/27/how-to-delete-an-app-you-consented-to-in-azure-ad/